# Run Test for unequal probability

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to figure out if a sequence is random or not using Run Test and My question is :

1) Is run test can only applied when the probability between success and fail is the same? (e.g. when head is 0.5 and tail is also 0.5)

2) What if I want to do a run test when the probabilities aren't equal (e.g. when head is 0.6 and tail is 0.4)